# Polish Notation Implementation

Tags: java

I want to write a program to calculate output  given arithmetical expression . Like that:

My input is: * + * + 1 2 + 3 4 5 6
My output should be: 156

I wrote a Java program to do  this using Stack data type. 
Here is my Java program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;


public class Main {
   public  static  void main(String args[]){
       Stack stack =new Stack();

       String input;

       String trimmedInput[];
       int output;
       int number1,number2;
       int countOfNumber,j;

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("put your arithmetical expression. Using Space between ");
       input=scanner.nextLine();

       trimmedInput=input.split("\\s+");

//       for(String a:trimmedInput)
//           System.out.println(a);


       countOfNumber=trimmedInput.length;


       for(j=0;j<countOfNumber;j++) {

               if (isNumeric(trimmedInput[j])) {
                   stack.push(trimmedInput[j]);

               }
                if (trimmedInput[j].equals("+")) {
                   number1 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                    number2 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                   output = number1 + number2;

                   stack.push(output);

               }

               if(trimmedInput[j].equals("-")){
                   number1 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                   number2 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                   output = number1-number2;

                   stack.push(output);
               }
                if(trimmedInput[j].equals("*")){
                    number1 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                    number2 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                   output = number1*number2;

                   stack.push(output);
               }
               if(trimmedInput[j].equals("/")){
                   number1 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                   number2 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;

                   output = number1/number2;

                   stack.push(output);
               }

           }

       while(!stack.isEmpty())
           System.out.println(stack.pop());


   }
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Ok. Here is my problem. If I want to calculate `* + * + 1 2 + 3 4 5 6` something like that, my compiler gives an error like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException    
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)     
at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)   
at Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

Here is my 41. row at code:

```
number1 = Integer.parseInt((String) stack.pop()) ;
```

I cannot figured out what is problem in my code. I'm new at Java. Please help me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This means that you are trying to take elements out of stack even though it is empty!

Comment: You should traverse from right-to-left. Take a look at this example of prefix evaluation:  http://www.manojagarwal.co.in/evaluation-of-prefix-expression/

Comment: Yes my friend. I know it but I cannot understand my code gives this error. I'm doing push my stack in my code.

Comment: And hint: you should learn how to add A) helpful "trace" statements to your code or B) how to use a debugger. You do not other people to **observe** what your code is doing in detail! the essence of becoming a programmer is the curiosity to figure yourself "what the hell is going on here". Asking other people is valid, but should be your *last* resort. For example you could dump your full stack during each step.

Comment: Your code is giving you error because you are parsing from left-to-right. So the first string it gets is "*" - star. So, it checks that it's a star, and pops from the stack. But, the stack is empty!! So, you should traverse from right-to-left and when you find number push into stack, and when you find operator, do the operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving you error because you are parsing from left-to-right. So the first string it gets is "*" - star. So, it checks that it's a star, and pops from the stack. But, the stack is empty!! So, you should traverse from right-to-left and when you find number push into stack, and when you find an operator, do the operation

```
for (int i = trimmedInput.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (isNumeric(trimmedInput[i])) stack.push(trimmedInput[i]);

    else if (trimmedInput[i].equals("*")) {
        // here you might get StackEmptyException if your expression is invalid
        // if you want to avoid that, then use try-catch and throw your custom InvalidExpressionExceptiono
        number1 = Integer.parseInt((String)stack.pop());
        number2 = Integer.parseInt((String)stack.pop());
        output = number1*number2;
        stack.push(output);
    }
    .
    .
    . // do the same for other operators
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

Shouldn't you push all operators into the stack, and pop it out after you see two operands ? (You will have two operands when one is at the top of the stack, and the other just comes in i.e. `trimmedInput[j]`).

Comment: **sees the first trimmedInput[0] as *, it pushes it into the stack**. This never happens, because the first star ( * ) is never pushed into the stack. Check OP's if-conditions. The first one checks if the string is a number or not. The exception is occuring because the program tries to pop 2 numbers and there is nothing in the stack. Operators are never **push**ed into the stack in this program, and for good reason

Comment: You are right.  I was following the logic in my head and I got it wrong.  I updated my answer above.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That wouldn't work either. You can trace through OP's example and see that the only way to evaluate prefix is to traverse from right-to-left. Also, you shouldn't push operators onto the stack. Take a look at [prefix evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution for above problem ..**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Expression
{
   static int i = 0 ;
   static Stack stack = new Stack<>();
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = in.next();
    input += in.nextLine();
    char expr[] = input.toCharArray();

    for(int j = expr.length-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
    {
        stack.push(process(expr[j]));
    }
    System.out.println("Result is : " + stack.pop());
}
public static int process(char val)
{
    int res = val;
    int flag = 0;
    if(val == '+')
    {
        flag = 1 ;
        res = (Integer)stack.pop() + (Integer)stack.pop();
    }
    else if(val == '-')
    {
        flag =1 ;
        res = (Integer)stack.pop() - (Integer)stack.pop();
    }
    else if(val == '*')
    {
        flag =1 ;
        res = (Integer)stack.pop() * (Integer)stack.pop();
    }
    else if(val == '/')
    {
        flag =1 ;
        res = ((Integer)stack.pop() / (Integer)stack.pop());
    }

    if(flag == 1)
        return res;
    else
        return res-48;
}
public static void print()
{
    int k = i;
    while(--k >= 0)
    {
        System.out.print(stack.peek() + " : ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
}
```