# Java calculator in normal Polish notation

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a calculator right now.  For reasons of simplicity, I would like to be able to use only "*,+,-" at the beginning. So far my basic framework looks like this.

```
public class calculator{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    parse(scanner);
}

public static Expr parse(String input) {
    return parse(new Scanner(input));
}

public static Expr parse(Scanner input) {

    return null;
}
```

My idea is to convert the input into a kind of tree of different objects and then evaluate it from the root. Now I don't know which data structure is most suitable for it and what would be the best way to implement these interfaces.

```
interface Expr {
Expr[] children();
int eval();
}
//Represents the binary operations "+,-,*"
interface BinOp extends Expr {
Expr left();

Expr right();
}
//Represents the unary operation "minus"
interface UnaryOp extends Expr {
Expr operand();
}

//Represents a number 
interface Constant extends Expr {
int val();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polish Notation Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212338/polish-notation-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to implement the explicit tree. If the user types in the full expression, you can evaluate it on the fly using a stack.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a collection such as an ArrayList, performing a search from the [-1]th element (and moving right to left) with a statement to check for the first operator, then performing that operation on the elements to the right of that index.